# Python authentication problem with SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, authentication, twisted

I have a Database in python with 2 fields: Username and passHash. The DB is ok, i already checked and all the parameters are correct. Then i need an authentication system that will look each row for the username, if it finds, look the 2nd field for the password, if not the same as user-provided, return "pass incorrect". but the problem is: how can i do it so the system will loop through all the rows and when it finishes, it will return "User doesn't exists".. Because now it returns user not found in the first row searched, sounds freaking noob but let's go D:

Ps. using twisted and sqlite3

```
    def authenticate(self, username, password):
    playerDB.execute('''SELECT * FROM playerData''')
    for row in playerDB:
        if row[0] == username:
            if row[1] == password:
                if username in ADMIN_NAMES:
                    self.server.sendOutput("Admin authentication: %s" % username)
                    logging.info("Admin authentication: %s" % username)
                return "Authenticated"
            else:
                logging.info("Authentication Fail: %s" % username)
                return "Password doesn't matches username."

        else:
            return "This player doesn't exists."
```

Comment: Have you considered writing an SQL query *other* than a `SELECT * FROM playerData'''?

Comment: Sorry, i am begginer in SQL so i don't really know too much.. examples would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your second `else` clause out to the `for` loop instead of the outer `if` statement. If you get to the end of the loop without an error, break, or return, it will be executed.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for the simple answer, that was just what i needed! :D

Comment: Please click the check mark next to my answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

From a security standpoint, you should *not* tell unauthenticated users that their username wasn't found, or that their username was found but the password didn't match.

By providing this information, you are giving potential attackers more information about the way they can attack.

If an attacker can try common usernames, and then try common passwords, he's not going to have to work nearly as hard, or try nearly as many combinations of username/password, before finding a match.

If instead, you just tell unauthenticated users the same message every time: "That username or password did not match" regardless of the reason *why* they have been refused authentication (weather they supplied an invalid username, an invalid password, or are being blocked because they triggered an abuse detector), then an attacker has no idea if they are getting closer to success, and will have to try passwords even on usernames that might not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = playerDB.execute('''SELECT * FROM playerData WHERE Username='{0}' '''.format(username))
if len(result) == 1: # user found
else : # user not found
```

Comment: Nah, but i need to know the username...and please if the answer was more simplified like the bit of code i proviced it would be easier to understand for me :)